# finding minimal difference

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, minimum

I have an array A=[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5...] and I want to find two elements of the array, say A[i] and A[j] such that i is less than j and A[j]-A[i] is minimal.

Would this code do the job:

```
def findMinDifference(A):
    Unsorted=[]
    minDiff=1000000
    Unsorted=A
    Sorted=quickSort(A)
    for i in range(0,len(Sorted)):
        if i>=1:
         SmallElement=Sorted[i-1]
         indexOfSmaller=Unsorted.index(SmallElement)
         BigElement=Sorted[i]
         indexOfBig=Unsorted.index(BigElement)
        if indexOfSmaller<inexOfBig:
             diff=Sorted[i]-Sorted[i-1]
             if diff<minDiff:
                 minDiff=diff
    return minDiff
```

Comment: I think you can answer your own question by testing that code.

Comment: Aside: it's hard to tell (and the formatting has been edited since), but your indentation looks weird to me, and that's sometimes a sign of mixed tabs-and-spaces in the original.  You might want to run your code using `python -tt your_program_name.py` to check for inconsistent whitespace, just in case.

Comment: @Blender do you have any thoughts on the correctness of the algorithm ?

Comment: @user220595 use `minDif = float('inf')`. Checking `.index()` has an O(N) cost so your algorithm would be really slow for big lists. O(n^2) I believe.

Comment: Also use lowercase variable names please. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ Also depending on your quicksort implementation your algorithm could even be slower but I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be updated a bit:

```
a = [1,2,5,9,10,20,21,45]
a, size = sorted(a), len(a)

res = [a[i + 1] - a[i] for i in xrange(size) if i+1 < size]

print "MinDiff: {0}, MaxDiff: {1}.".format(min(res), max(res))
```

In two words - finding min or max diff can be simplified as getting min/max element of a list that consist of differences for each pair of elements from the sorted original list of values

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools` pairwise](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
        "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return izip(a, b)

>>> nums = [1, 3, 7, 13, 9, 18, 22]
>>> min(pairwise(sorted(nums)), key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the sort.  You can adapt this pseudocode.

```
for i = 0; i < array.length; i++
    for j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++
        if a[j] - a[i] < min
            min = a[j] - a[i]
 return min
```

Comment: Maybe he wants to get a positive minmal difference.

Comment: The difference does not have to be positive but the runtime has to be O(nlog(n)) not O(n^2). Would my approach give the right answer in O(nlog(n)) runtime ?

Comment: Good point, unclear to me right now, at a restaurant and have been drinking :)   But this looks like a great case for a barage of unit tests.  If your approach is *CORRECT* it does appear to be O(n*log(n))

Comment: @DavidWilliams It's not O(n log(n)). See my comment above

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, using more iterables and more relying on defaults:

```
from itertools import imap, islice, izip

def find_min_diff(iterable, sort_func=sorted):
    sorted_iterable = sort_func(iterable)
    return min(imap(
        lambda a, b: b - a,
        izip(sorted_iterable, islice(sorted_iterable, 1)),
    ))
```

Comment: That seems to be fine, but would my approach give the right answer in O(nlog(n)) runtime ?